# Question on common table expression using mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I'm currently working on solving this SQL question on Hackerrank, accessible via https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/interviews/problem?isFullScreen=true, using MySQL common table expression. If I just do this, it is fine.

```
SELECT challenge_id, SUM(total_submissions) AS cid_tot_sub, SUM(total_accepted_submissions) AS cid_tot_acc_sub
      FROM Submission_Stats
      GROUP BY challenge_id
```

However, when I attempt it using MySQL common table expressions, I encounter the following error that I don't understand. Could you please advise? Thank you very much.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 55: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte_ss AS (
      SELECT challenge_id, SUM(total_submissions) AS cid_tot_sub, SU' at line 2
```

```
WITH 
    cte_ss AS (
      SELECT challenge_id, SUM(total_submissions) AS cid_tot_sub, SUM(total_accepted_submissions) AS cid_tot_acc_sub
      FROM Submission_Stats
      GROUP BY challenge_id
    ),
    cte_vs AS (
      SELECT challenge_id, SUM(total_views) AS cid_tot_views, SUM(total_unique_views) AS cid_tot_uniq_views
      FROM View_Stats
      GROUP BY challenge_id
    )
select * from cte_ss;
```

Comment: What  version of MySQL are you using? CTE was added in 8.0.

Comment: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 when I do `SELECT VERSION();`
I've used MySQL CTE for another question on Hackerrank, and it worked fine.

Comment: I can't explain why it worked previously. It doesn't exist in 5.7.

Comment: The environment where the question (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem?isFullScreen=true) runs MySQL common table expressions without any issues I mentioned is 8.0.33.

Comment: Does HackerRank have different MySQL versions for different questions?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: If it works for one question but not another, that's the only explanation I can think of. Can you reproduce the problem when using MySQL 8.x outside of HackerRank?

Comment: If `SELECT VERSION();` produces different results for different problems, they must be using different versions. I'm not sure why they would do that.